# What is the difference between Touch and Stylus WPF

Tags: wpf, touch

I want to add touch-features to my wpf api. I m confused of how to use. There is Gesture, Touch and Stylus.

I could not find out where Stylus and Touch differ from each other.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Touch:

> *"Provides an application-level service that processes multitouch input from the operating system and raises the FrameReported event."*

Stylus:

> *"Provides access to general information about a tablet pen."*

However if you develop an application with touch-screen support you will realize that their events aren't relly isolated and separated due bubbled events (see attached image).

[image]

You can read about manipulations [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://nui.joshland.org/2010/04/why-wont-wpf-controls-work-with-touch.html).