# Press and hold to learn option

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

Hi I have a C# WPF POS application which runs also on Touchscreen computers. In a particular case I have a ListBox where Items will be displayed. I have a Template for view so the name is displayed.

There would be chance where Name of the Items is too long. In that case, I may need to truncate the Name to well fit for the view.

I need to show the full name by using "Press and hold to learn option".  Its so simple in web applications since we have mouse over functionality.

How can I achieve this using WPF?

Comment: have you ever tried tooltip?

Comment: @Hiber  How come tooltip works for Touchscreens?

Comment: @paqogomez I am asking a suggestion to start implement. I haven't tried anything yet

Comment: @anees so your real question is you don't know how to handle events with touch? WPF provides raw touch API and Manipulation APIs, you can have a try with Manipulation APIs first I think.

Answer (score 1):

This question is far not so dummy as it seems to be. I also had the same issue a while ago. I must admit it is difficult to create a user friendly interface on touchscreen since you don't have the ancient tool: tooltip, onmouseover, position, etc and the resolution itself is lower in some case. It is easy to forget, specially if your app has to work both with touch and with mouse. Actually the real solution depends on hw / sw.

1. If you have multi-touch screen, you can define some multi touch manipulation to display tooltip, e.g.: zoom. But in this case you mostly also occour a selection, which can be unwanted.
2. Some modern touchscreens also recognize if your finder is over an element, you don't need to touch it. In this case OnMouseOver is supposed to work.
3. When those two above don't work you still have a workaround to define a custom button per element to show tooltip (e.g a small icon).
4. To implement *press and hold* you can override TouchDown and TouchUp events and messure time, but be careful since in this case simple touch / single click also happens due bubbled events. So you need to cancel (handled = true) bubble. More about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464898/what-is-the-difference-between-touch-and-stylus-wpf/19973971#19973971).

You can read more about touch and manipulation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Andras..I am thinking to implement Option 3.  In that "to Show tooltip" defines what. I mean on clicking custom buttom How to show tooltip?

Comment: You can open it with an AttachedProperty and a Button. Register Button click handler to change tooltip open state to true. Here is a working solution, however it is not attached property http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116842/can-i-explicity-show-tooltip-on-mouse-click-event-in-wpf.